# Show/hide columns depending upon index

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table

```
<div ng-controller="checkBoxController">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p ng-repeat='(key, val) in employees[0]'>
              <label>
                <input ng-model='colSettings[$index]' type="checkbox" />{{ key }}</label>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="saveSelectedColumn()">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tableDataReset();">Reset</button>

      <table class="table-condensed" id="employeeTable" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-if='colSettings[$index]' ng-repeat='(key, val) in employees[0]' class="name">{{ key }}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
            <td ng-if='colSettings[$index]'>{{employee.name}}</td>
            <td ng-if='colSettings[$index]'>{{employee.age}}</td>
            <td ng-if='colSettings[$index]'>{{employee.gender}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <a href="" title="Column Setting" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Settings</a> {{ colSettings }}
    </div>
  </div>

 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('checkBoxController', function($scope) {
   $scope.employees = [{
     name: 'John',
     age: 25,
     gender: 'boy'
   }, {
     name: 'Jessie',
     age: 30,
     gender: 'girl'
   }];

   $scope.colSettings = [true, true, true];

   $scope.tableDataReset = function() {
     $scope.employees = [{
       name: 'John',
       age: 25,
       gender: 'boy'
     }, {
       name: 'Jessie',
       age: 30,
       gender: 'girl'
     }];
   };
 });
```

Have list of table data with a settings button, onclick of which a modal dialog opens. This modal dialog contains that contains checkbox equal to the number columns in the table. User selects any of the checkbox & close button, then the table is filtered depending upon the checkbox that are checked (i.e. those checkboxes that are checked only that columns are visible within the table). 
Currently storing true & false for checked & unchecked checkboxes in colSettings array. Also on checkbox selection currently hiding columns which I want on modal close button. Using above code I am able to hide th but not td along with its data.

Follow the plnk
http://plnkr.co/edit/G5bT7G?p=preview

Comment: what do you have in saveSelectedColumn method?

Comment: Currently on checkbox check & uncheck am showing/ hiding table columns. I want to do that on close button of overlay i.e saveSelectedColumn().

Answer (score 2):

If you are having more column, dynamically update everything

```
  <table class="table-condensed" id="employeeTable" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-if="val" ng-repeat="(key, val) in colSettings" class="name">{{ key }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
        <td ng-if="colSettings[key]" ng-repeat="(key,value) in employee">{{value}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/y67yPg?p=preview)**

Comment: It works. But my table will be having many columns, currently have included only. So everytime hardcoding the index won't make sense. Is there any other alternative?. Also $index will always give the current index so don't know why there is issue.

Comment: You are using the index of the employee not  the index for columns, here is the issue

Comment: @migueref ok. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it dynamic so that there is no requirement for you to remember indexes

```js
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('checkBoxController', function($scope) {
   $scope.employees = [{
     name: 'John',
     age: 25,
     gender: 'boy'
   }, {
     name: 'Jessie',
     age: 30,
     gender: 'girl'
   }];
$scope.getColSettingForRow = function(key){
 var keys = Object.keys($scope.employees[0]);
 var index  = keys.indexOf(key);
 return index;
}
   $scope.colSettings = [true, true, true];

   $scope.tableDataReset = function() {
     $scope.employees = [{
       name: 'John',
       age: 25,
       gender: 'boy'
     }, {
       name: 'Jessie',
       age: 30,
       gender: 'girl'
     }];
   };
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="checkBoxController">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p ng-repeat='(key, val) in employees[0]'>
              <label>
                <input ng-model='colSettings[$index]' type="checkbox" />{{ key }}</label>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="saveSelectedColumn()">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="tableDataReset();">Reset</button>
    
      <table class="table-condensed" id="employeeTable" border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-if='colSettings[$index]' ng-repeat='(key, val) in employees[0]' class="name">{{ key }}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees"> 
            <td ng-if='colSettings[getColSettingForRow("name")]'>{{employee.name}}</td>
            <td ng-if='colSettings[getColSettingForRow("age")]'>{{employee.age}}</td>
            <td ng-if='colSettings[getColSettingForRow("gender")]'>{{employee.gender}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <a href="" title="Column Setting" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Settings</a> {{ colSettings }}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have keys id & created date as well within my json object, but need to ignore them when applying repeat on check box list & table th lists. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to hide them. Just ignore them under checkbox and tr that's fine. It will work. If you want proper answer. Please send me the sample so that i can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I will to explain an alternative.
You must make a ng-repeat for colSettings, because you are using the index for employees, this is why is not working.

If you record all colSettings with a value boolean per example you could show or hide with this value, but you would be  using the index of colSettings because in your ng repeat you  would be loops through you colSetting and you could print the values for the visible columns.

Comment: You could question for more info if you have any question

Comment: Unable to get it. Is it possible for you to implement & show?